# ASP.NET - Install Visual Studio without IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I already have IIS installed on my localhost.

I just use sublime text editor to create my website.

But now i have problem in debugging the vb code. So I decided to install Visual Studio Express.

So, can I install the Visual Studio Express without conflicting the existing website?

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE. Not a web server. It won't interfere with existing web sites

Comment: if you mean IIS Conflicting with Visual Studio builtin IIS, there is no worry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

Visual Studio uses IIS Express, that works on random ports different from standard ones (80 etc)

So youll'not have problem with existing IIS websites.